# Userfom - Change TextBox Value to show sum of Comboboxes values

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox, userform

My graduation projects has an Excel VBA Application with a userform. In a page of the userform, there are 9 comboboxes that contain numerical alternatives (5, 10, 15, 20, ...) that are actually weights (Which is why the sum of the chosen weights should be 100 (100%)). In order to make sure that the sum of the chosen numbers equals 100, I added a textbox in the userform that shows the sum of the weights after each change in the combobox. Now I can't get this textbox to show the sum.

[image]

My attempt at the code is :

```
Private Sub calculate()
Dim total As Integer
    total = IIf(IsNull(ComboBox1), 0, CInt(ComboBox1.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox2), 0, CInt(ComboBox2.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox3), 0, CInt(ComboBox3.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox4), 0, CInt(ComboBox4.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox5), 0, CInt(ComboBox5)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox6), 0, CInt(ComboBox6.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox7), 0, CInt(ComboBox7.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox8), 0, CInt(ComboBox8.Value)) + IIf(IsNull(ComboBox9), 0, CInt(ComboBox9.Value))
End sub
```

This is a sub that calculates the sum. And then after each combobox change (i.e. the events ComboBox_Change() ) the textbox in question would be updated to show the sum (which is the variable total defined before) like this :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Call calculate
TextBox9.Value = total
End Sub
```

Now I belive the idea is correct, but I can't get the code to work, I get the error "Type mismatch (13)"

Any help would be great, also English is not my first language so please don't mind any mistakes.
Thanks

Comment: For starters, `TextBox9.Value = total` should be in the `calculate` sub as the change code doesn't know what that is.

Comment: Hey, @SJR I got your point, after doing this modification, I still have the error "type mismatch", it is related to the line that begins with "total = " in the calculate sub ...